# ARM processor, Debian, error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, linux, arm, embedded-linux

Trying to perform SPI communication on ARM processor running on Linux Debian. 
Unable to compile the code below (error: expected primary-expression before '.' token) 
 g++ comm.cpp -o comm
I am not sure how I can compile this code Is there something I am missing ? Thank you.

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
.tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
.rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
.len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
.delay_usecs = delay,
.speed_hz = speed,
.bits_per_word = bits
};
```

Comment: That is C, not C++. You need to compile the code as C, with a compiler that supports C99 or newer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That leading dot syntax is valid in C99? What I get for not writing any C in 20 years... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is valid, but the initializers have to be compile time constants. So the validity of the code above depends on `tx`, `rx`, etc.

Comment: this works in c++ also, which version of g++ compiler are you using.